# Connection pooling in java using HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, connection-pooling

- How can I create a pool of connections using HttpClient?
- I have to make frequent connections to the same server. Is it worth creating such a pool?
- Is it possible to keep HTTP connections live and use them for various requests, and if yes how can I do so?

Comment: Good read on the subject:
https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[assuming Java, and Apache's HttpClient]

Use a [ThreadSafeClientConnManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html). Pass a single global instance to the constructor of every HttpClient instance. I don't think there's any point in pooling the HttpClients themselves.

Comment: It was later replaced by `org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`

Comment: All the methods and constructors are marked deprecated in the documentation of ThreadSafeClientConnManager

Answer (score 25):

I have spent recent days working on this so just want to share some "everyone-known" knowledges with you.

First, as you are dealing with the same server, it is recommended to use a single HTTP client to execute your requests. With the help of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`, your client can be used to execute multiple requests concurrently. The official example of multithreaded request execution can be found [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e405).

Secondly, HTTP/1.1 (and enhanced versions of HTTP/1.0) allows HTTP clients to keep the connections open after transactions complete so that it can be reused for future requests. This is often refered as **Persistent Connection**.

Also for the purpose of reusing client for multiple requests, the response header from a server often include an attribute call `Keep-Alive` that contain the time current connection will be kept alive. Besides that, Apache Http Client also provides you an interface `ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy`to customize your own policy for reusing connection.

Comment: Just want to know, when you can set connection timeout and socket timeout in the `ConnectionConfig` for each `HttpClient` previous to 4.x, now they are absent from `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`. Now, how to set timeouts? And, where to set `http.conn-manager.timeout` which is the time to wait before getting a connection?

Answer (score 22):

`PoolingClientConnectionManager` is Deprecated now . from (4.3 version) use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.

Comment: Similar topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be

Answer (score 17):

ThreadSafeClientConnManager is deprecated now, use [PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html) instead.

Comment: `PoolingClientConnectionManager` is deprecated, use [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) (hello from 2015)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be

Answer (score 8):

For HttpClient 4x:

> ThreadSafeClientConnManager ... manages a **pool of client
> connections** and is able to service connection requests from multiple execution threads.
>
> **Connections are pooled on a per route basis**. A request for a route for which the manager already
> has a persistent connection available in the pool will be serviced by leasing a **connection from
> the pool** rather than creating a brand new connection.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of an Apache HttpClient 4.3 pool of connections which do not require authentication:

```
public class PoolOfHttpConnections{
   static String[] urisToGet = {"http://www.site1.com", "http://www.site2.com"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
           // create a thread for each link
           GetThread[] threads = new GetThread[urisToGet.length];
           for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
               HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urisToGet[i]);
               threads[i] = new GetThread(httpClient, httpget);
           }

           // start the threads
           for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
               threads[j].start();
           }
           // join the threads
           for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
               threads[j].join();
           }
    } //end main

    private static class GetThread extends Thread {

            private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
            private final HttpContext context;
            private final HttpGet httpget;

            public GetThread(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, HttpGet httpget) {
                   this.httpClient = httpClient;
                   this.context = HttpClientContext.create();
                   this.httpget = httpget;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                   try {
                       CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget, context);
                       try {
                           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                           System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                           Date date = new Date();
                           System.out.println("Beginning*******************");
                           System.out.println(date.toString());
                           System.out.println("There are "+urisToGet.length+" threads running in parallel!");
                           System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                           if (entity != null) {
                              System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
                           }
                           System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                           EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                       } finally {
                         response.close();
                         System.out.println("End*******************");
                       }
                   } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
                          // Handle protocol errors
                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                          // Handle I/O errors
                   }
            }
    } /*end private class*/  }//end public class PoolOfHttpConnections
```

Answer (score -9):

HttpClient has already have a connection pool.So you do not need to create it. Just use it.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong . Httpclient has no connection pool by default

Comment: For reviewers: [incorrect answers are *not* Very Low Quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality) Please vote "Looks OK" on this.