# HTTP Connection pool

Tags: spring, tomcat, connection-pooling

I need to set up an HTTP connection pool in a Spring app on a Tomcat server.

We are debating whether to define the pool at the application or at the server level (applicationContext.xml vs server.xml).

My problem is: I've looked and I've looked, but I just can't find any info on doing either.

For now, I'm working with `org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager` inside my class, and it's working ok.

How would I be able to define a pool outside my Java code and work with it from there?

Comment: What do you need this pool for?

Comment: In short, we're Springifying a webcrawler that runs through websites we create(d).

Comment: In that case, it should be done on the application level, as you've - also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14280762/687514).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration reference you are looking for for tomcat 7:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation

Here is also another SO post on the same subject: [How to increase number of threads in tomcat thread pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402681/how-to-increase-number-of-threads-in-tomcat-thread-pool)