# Pool of connections for RestSharp

Tags: c#, connection-pooling, restsharp

Is there some way to build my own connection pool.

I'm developing an application which's connecting to a server. Each time it needs to ask for someting to server, it creates a connection and release it.

I'd like to provide a transparent way to get a connection from a pool of them.

I'm using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to build my requests:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value");
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123");

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

So, perhaps the question would be aroung how to create a pool for [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)? Or, How to configure [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for getting connections from a pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may see in RestSharp [source code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/5118e3d586038f34f4e4416863a3dfc72c161712/RestSharp/Http.Sync.cs#L201), RestSharp is based on well-known `System.Net` classes, such as [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) and `HttpWebResponse`. These classes already use own pipeline.

This pipeline may be tuned if needed:
[Understanding System.Net Connection Management and ServicepointManager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adarshk/2005/01/02/understanding-system-net-connection-management-and-servicepointmanager/)

> If application continues to make requests, all pending requests would
>   be queued on the ServicePoint and processed sequentially. If pipeline
>   is turned on, then request is send on the connection and put in the
>   queue of the connection. If pipelining is turned off then request
>   would remain on the queue of the servicepoint and would be sending on
>   the connection, as soon as free connection is available.

Related question: [Is HTTP connection pooling possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085708/is-http-connection-pooling-possible)