# Deprecated Java HttpClient - How hard can it be?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

All I'm trying to do is download some JSON and deserialize it into an object. I haven't got as far as downloading the JSON yet.

Almost every single HttpClient example I can find, including those on the apache site looks something like...

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public void blah() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ...
}
```

However, Netbeans tells me that `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. I've tried googling for `DefaultHttpClient deprecated` and as many other variations as I can think of and can't find any useful results, so I'm obviously missing something.

What is the correct Java7 way to download the contents of a webpage? Is there really no decent Http Client as part of the language? I find that hard to believe.

My Maven dependency for this is...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: NetBeans is telling you wrong, or you are misreading something. `DefaultHttpClient` is definitely not deprecated. What version did you specify in your POM?

Comment: in 4.3-alpha1 it seems to be deprecated

Comment: @sreemanth Thanks but although I eventually intend to use this for Json, the actual question is not related to Json at all.

Comment: You are right the httpclient API is a trainwreck

Comment: I would recommend you set the version to some major release number instead of LATEST. This will allow you to manually control the upgrade process and not let Maven decide for you.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Sure, when you've finished writing it... But for your first piece of code in a new project, why not use Latest? Once you've actually got a dependency on a specific version, absolutely nail it down

Comment: @Basic it may change any time while you work on it even in a new project, this may be confusing if you did not set it yourself. For example it worked and compiled and you commit the code. Someone else arrives the next day, checkout and it does not even compile because the LATEST version changed. Of course you do what you want but I would avoid using it for this reason (versionning).

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Let's agree to disagree

Comment: I think it's worth noting here that with Java 11 now comes a built in HttpClient and possibly freedom from the apache dependency for some applications, depending on your needs.

Comment: @CaseyMurray That's very welcome indeed, if long overdue.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Relevant imports:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Usage:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

EDIT (after Jules' suggestion):

As the `build()` method returns a `CloseableHttpClient` which *is-a* `AutoClosable`, you can place the declaration in a try-with-resources  statement (Java 7+):

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {

    // use httpClient (no need to close it explicitly)

} catch (IOException e) {

    // handle

}
```

Comment: This is giving me - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Comment: You're using version below 4.3 (and it should be Apache HTTPClient, not Commons HTTPClient)

Comment: Note that the return value is a `CloseableHttpClient`, which you should be closing after use.  It implements `AutoCloseable`, so you can use it in a try-with-resources statement in Java 7+: `try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = ...) { ... }`.

Comment: how to build within a Spring xml config. file?

Comment: CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); this work for me

Comment: **Question:** Should we hold on to the HttpClientBuilder instance returned by the `create()` static method? Or can we just call `create()` whenever we need one?... Btw, `import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder` for anyone who needs that. *[Dislikes answers without import statements. Don't worry I still upvoted :)]*

Comment: can also use     `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()`

Comment: With API 23 this becomes much more complicated: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger use OkHttp on Android. They messed up with a forked Apache Http Client, that is now legacy.

Comment: i am getting this error "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:977)"

Answer (score 60):

IMHO the accepted answer is correct but misses some 'teaching' as it does not explain how to come up with the answer.
For all deprecated classes look at the [**JavaDoc**](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) (if you do not have it either download it or [go online](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)), it will hint at which class to use to replace the old code. Of course it will not tell you everything, but this is a start. Example:

```
...
 *
 * @deprecated (4.3) use {@link HttpClientBuilder}.  <----- THE HINT IS HERE !
 */
@ThreadSafe
@Deprecated
public class DefaultHttpClient extends AbstractHttpClient {
```

Now you have the class to use, `HttpClientBuilder`, as there is no constructor to get a **builder** instance you may guess that there must be a static method instead: `create`. Once you have the builder you can also guess that as for most builders there is a **build method**, thus:

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

**AutoClosable:**

As Jules hinted in the comments, the returned class implements `java.io.Closable`, so if you use Java 7 or above you can now do:

```
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {...}
```

The advantage is that you do not have to deal with finally and nulls.

**Other relevant info**

Also make sure to read about [connection pooling](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) and set the [timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256157/apache-http-setsockettimout-vs-setconnecttimout-vs-setconnectionrequesttimeout).

Answer (score 13):

**[Examples from Apache](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/examples.html)** use this:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

The class `org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients` is there since version 4.3.

The code for `HttpClients.createDefault()` is the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15336796) in here.

Comment: get error "Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier"

when use HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

Answer (score 7):

It got deprecated in version `4.3-alpha1` which you use because of the `LATEST` version specification. If you take a look at the javadoc of the class, it tells you what to use instead: `HttpClientBuilder`.

In the latest stable version (`4.2.3`) the `DefaultHttpClient` is not deprecated yet.

Comment: Thanks for the response - Netbeans isn't showing any JavaDocs for any of the org.apache stuff - but I suppose that's a different problem

Comment: You probably don't have the sources attached to the library. I don't use Netbeans, but I guess there is a way to ask it to download the sources of the dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using the below method if you are trying to read the json data only.

```
URL requestUrl=new URL(url);
URLConnection con = requestUrl.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
int cp;
try {
    while((cp=rd.read())!=-1){
    sb.append((char)cp);
  }
 catch(Exception e){
 }
 String json=sb.toString();
```

Comment: The questions says `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated and you suggest using it in your answer...

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach. I've already gone with the acdepted answer but this looks light-weight enough that I'll give it a try next time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) to build the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) instead of using DefaultHttpClient

ex:

```
MinimalHttpClient httpclient = new HttpClientBuilder().build();

 // Prepare a request object
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");
```

Comment: Why `new HttpClientBuilder()` and not `HttpClientBuilder.create()`?

Answer (score 2):

**You could add the following Maven dependency.**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**You could use following import in your java code.**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGett;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
```

**You could use following code block in your java code.**

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new HttpGet("http://example.domain/someuri");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpUriRequest);
System.out.println("Response:"+response);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but how is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Most of answers are psuedo codes, I tried doing an end-to-end basic working Java code with Apache HTTP Client API along with maven dependency. Nothing great though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I have applied to the problem that httpclient deprecated in this version of android 22

```
 public static String getContenxtWeb(String urlS) {
    String pagina = "", devuelve = "";
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlS);
        HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        conexion.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        if (conexion.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conexion.getInputStream()));
            String linea = reader.readLine();
            while (linea != null) {
                pagina += linea;
                linea = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();

            devuelve = pagina;
        } else {
            conexion.disconnect();
            return null;
        }
        conexion.disconnect();
        return devuelve;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return devuelve;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For the original issue, I would request you to apply below logic:

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost();
```