# Why I am getting DefaultHttpClient is deprecated?

Tags: java, httpclient

I am working on a project in which I need to make a call to my service and my service will return the data back in JSON format. And I don't need to serialize this JSON response to any POJO, I just need to get the data back as String. And this application is very performance critical so `HttpClient` has to be pretty fast

So I decided to use Apache HttpClient or is there any better alternative which I can use?

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("some-url");
request.addHeader("Context", "some-value");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
String response =  IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

But it complains that `The type DefaultHttpClient is deprecated` so maybe they have new version of `HttpClient` or some other way of making a HttpClient call to an URL?

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Looking at the documentation can you tell you that in a glimpse: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

Refer to this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be)

Answer (score 5):

From Apache HTTP Client API version 4.3 on wards, DefaultHttpClient is deprecated.

Use following maven dependency as an example.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Following import.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGett;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
```

Following code block.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new 
HttpGet("http://example.domain/someuri");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpUriRequest);
System.out.println("Response:"+response);
```