# HttpClientBuilder missing on Android?

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

Apache has deprecated DefaultHttpClient, but it seems this is not the case for Android, see also here [Deprecated Java HttpClient - How hard can it be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be)

Importing

```
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5
```

instead of

```
new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I would now use

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

to create an http client. This works fine in a Java project, but when used in an Android project, the following import is missing

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
```

while

```
HttpClient sendClient =  new DefaultHttpClient();
```

is not marked as deprecated in Android and compiles fine.

I don't want to add the Apache httpclient a second time (and if I would do so, Android Studio would exclude it anyhow).

The Android documentation says here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html#newInstance(java.lang.String) to use

```
AndroidHttpClient.new Instance(string)
```

to "get an http client with reasonable defaults".

Does anybody know what is the correct way of creating an HttpClient on Android, and what would be the userAgent string!?

Comment: basically u wanna just hit post request or is there anything u wanna achive with HttpClient

Comment: I am trying to create a long running http request to receive push notifications from a server.

Comment: I don't really know Android's push notifications yet, but I feel you should let Android deal with them. Don't have a service running only to get push notifications, this will waste battery. I found a tutorial about Android's push notifications, hope that helps: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: Thanks @ÜberLem, but PushNotifications is a completely different technology and the drawback is that it won't work with iOS. Android is on the receiving side, so sockets should not be a problem in terms of battery life. If anybody has a contrary opinion, please post it here.

Answer (score 6):

Google Android ships with an extremely outdated (pre-BETA) version of Apache HttpClient 4.0.

If you want to use newer Apache HttpClient APIs with Android you should consider using the [official Android port](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Comment: This answer is correct but it's better to use new port which doesn't add any suffixes: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this line in your app Gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```