# org.apache.http.client.httpclient is deprecated

Tags: java, android

I have one problem. In my

> android studio

i found  **`org.apache.http.client.httpclient is deprecated`**  *Please help me.*

Comment: i already use this solution

Comment: Use `HttpURLConnection` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Go to this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be

Comment: i used both of these solution also but error not resolved

Comment: You can still use apache's libraries even if it is deprecated. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37623038/1727132