# What are the Alternative of a deprecated files in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, httpclient

I have tried 
this `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'`  `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` and

```
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient' , version: '4.4.1.1'
```

but nothing happen its still in deprecated form.. 
what should i do? and what is the best solution?

Comment: even if you add library it will show as Deprecated, as Android marked them as deprecated recommends Use of "UrlConnection" or "HttpUrlConnection"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be