# Using Groovy's HTTPBuilder, how do you set timeouts

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I'm trying to set a connection timeout with Groovy HTTPBuilder and for the life of me can't find a way.

Using plain ol' URL it's easy:

```
def client = new URL("https://search.yahoo.com/search?q=foobar")
def result = client.getText( readTimeout: 1 )
```

This throws a SocketTimeoutException, but that's not quite what I want.  For a variety of reasons, I'd rather use HTTPBuilder or better RESTClient.

This does work:

```
    def client = new HTTPBuilder()
    def result = client.request("https://search.yahoo.com/", Method.GET, "*/*") { HttpRequest request ->
        uri.path = "search"
        uri.query = [q: "foobar"]
        request.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 1);
    }
```

However request.getParams() has been deprecated.

For the life of me I can't find a way to inject a proper RequestConfig into the builder.

Comment: Have you tried: `client.client.params.setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 1000)`

Comment: Needed this recently myself and came across this: https://gist.github.com/axeda/5189102

Comment: Setting a parameter works fine.  However, that method has been deprecated.  It seems HTTPBuilder hasn't been modernized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, I'm using 0.7.1:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
import org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients

def timeout = 10000 // millis
SocketConfig sc = SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(timeout).build()
RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).build()
def hc = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultSocketConfig(sc).setDefaultRequestConfig(rc).build()        
def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://search.yahoo.com/')
http.client = hc

http.get(path:'/search')
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume timeout is in millis? The docs do not say. :(

Comment: Yes its millis.

Answer (score 1):

pure HTTPBuilder:

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig

def TIMEOUT = 10000
def defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT)
        .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT)
        .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT)
        .build()
def client = new HTTPBuilder("uri")
client.setClient(HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).build())
```

RESTClient with everything:

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder

def restClient = new RESTClient("hostname")

//timeout
def TIMEOUT = 5000
def defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT)
        .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT)
        .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT)
        .build()

//basic user/password authentication
def credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "password")
def credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials)

//set ssl trust all, no ssl exceptions
def sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustSelfSignedStrategy.INSTANCE).build()
def sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)

//multithreaded connection manager
def multithreadedConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()

//build client with all this stuff
restClient.setClient(HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(multithreadedConnectionManager)
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
        .build())
```

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc, it appears you do it by using [AsyncHttpBuilder](http://javadox.com/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6/groovyx/net/http/AsyncHTTPBuilder.html) instead?  That class extends HTTPBuilder and it has a **setTimeout(int)** method.

Look at this:  http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2013/02/10/groovy-and-http/  According to that, it appears you might be able to follow the advice here to get a timeout on your connection:  [Java HTTP Client Request with defined timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout)

Comment: Thanks, good idea.  However, I looked at the code for AsyncHTTPBuilder.  It also uses the deprecated method of setting params.  I guess there's no better way.

Comment: Ok, i added a url to my answer.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks again, but the issue isn't about getting it to work - the timeout setting is fine.  The issue is that AsyncHTTPBuilder is using deprecated methods.  Check out line 211 [code](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/AsyncHTTPBuilder.java) .  client.getParams() is deprecated.

Comment: I sorta see what you mean here:  https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html

Comment: Yeah - you got it, djangofan.  Actually, I'm getting concerned as it seems HTTPBuilder might be a dead project.

Comment: I'm surprised the latest Groovy still uses that library.  Maybe there is a reason for it.  NO answer was given to this question:  https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/issues/57

Comment: It appears you MIGHT be able to get around the deprecation by using this method?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be

Answer (score -1):

I use like this

```
def timeOut = 10000
HTTPBuilder http = new HTTPBuilder('http://url.com')
http.client.params.setParameter('http.connection.timeout', new Integer(timeOut))
http.client.params.setParameter('http.socket.timeout', new Integer(timeOut))
```

Comment: This still uses `getParams()`, which OP does not want to use because it's deprecated.