# Apache HTTP - setSocketTimout vs setConnectTimout vs setConnectionRequestTimeout

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

What is the difference between `setSocketTimout`, `setConnectTimout` and `setConnectionRequestTimeout`?

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
            .setSocketTimeout(500)
            .setConnectTimeout(500)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(500)
            .build();
```

Comment: So what did you end up using ? A socket timeout of 500 seems a bit extreme, what if the network is slow ?

Answer (score 12):

`Connection timeout` is the timeout until a *connection with the server* is established.

`Socket timeout` is the *timeout to receive data*.

The method `setConnectionRequestTimeout` however is specific for configuring the connection manager. It returns the timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection from the connection manager. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Comment: What would you use for a typical application, 500 millis seems a bit short.

Answer (score 0):

**ConnectTimeOut**:- Refers the maximum time in milliseconds client will wait for connection establishment with server. Within give time the server must have established a connection with Client other it will throw an Exception.

**SocketTimeout**:- It defines maximum idle/ inactivity time in milliseconds between two consecutive data packets.

refer [javadocs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html) for more details