# RestTemplate not timing out after setting connectTimeout and readTimeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot infrastructure with few microservices. They communicating pretty well between each other. One of the microservices have some third party calls, calling some third party services through http.
I have defined my own RestTemplate and in the init() method I am setting connectTimeout and readTimeout.
From the stack traces I see that my rest template is used.

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
  }
```

The problem is that some of the requests are handing for few minutes and no exceptions are thrown. (my timeouts are much less - about 5-10 seconds)
What may be the cause? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Missing the call to setConnectionRequestTimeout(...);

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(...);
this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

[Spring RestTemplate timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout)

Comment: that was something I was thinking about, but can you clarify a bit more how that will behave? when we will have connect timeout and connectRequest timeout? thanks in advance.

Comment: @saferJo Hey, you can find clarification for the difference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256157/apache-http-setsockettimout-vs-setconnecttimout-vs-setconnectionrequesttimeout/44222752) .  Looking further into what you are trying to do I believe what you really want to set is the socketTimeout see (https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) section 8.