# Can rearch resource behind VPN from java app: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, linux, http, socketexception

I've got a very weird problem with HTTP connection from java.

Description: from machine **A**(source machine) i trying to get http response from machine **B**(10.13.0.69).

Important part: machine **B**(target) is located behind VPN tunnel.
Machine **B** is reachable from machine **A**. I have no problems, if i try to access this URL from machine A OS (with curl for example):

```
[root@Test-LAPP01 test]# curl http://10.13.0.69:7878/testGet && echo ""
{"result":["\"AlertServer testGet ok\" "]}
```

Problems starts when i trying to perform same request from java program, that located at machine A: i getting SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server.

Detailed description:

```
[root@Test-LAPP01 test]# cat contest.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class contest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                String url = "http://10.13.0.69:7878/testGet";
                try {
                        URL alert = new URL(url);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) alert.openConnection();
                        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "chrome");
                        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
                        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}

[root@Test-LAPP01 test]# curl http://10.13.0.69:7878/testGet && echo ""
{"result":["\"AlertServer testGet ok\" "]}

[root@Test-LAPP01 test]# java contest
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:851)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:848)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at contest.main(contest.java:12)
```

Note 1: from java app i CAN connect to external resourses, like google.com and have no issues with that.

Note 2: It works if i place target web server that i trying to reach (Machine B - 10.13.0.69) on same subnet with source machine A. So problem is somehow related to VPN.

I already tried to debug this and launched tcpdump on both machines and now i'm confused even more: i see all network requests on both sides.

So **short description**: i can reach destination URL from machine, but cant from java app.

UPD: updated code with @RedBoy recommendations. Now i've see this error:

```
апр 25, 2018 12:47:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://10.13.0.69:7878: The target server failed to respond
апр 25, 2018 12:47:24 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://10.13.0.69:7878
апр 25, 2018 12:47:55 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://10.13.0.69:7878: The target server failed to respond
апр 25, 2018 12:47:55 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://10.13.0.69:7878
апр 25, 2018 12:48:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://10.13.0.69:7878: The target server failed to respond
апр 25, 2018 12:48:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://10.13.0.69:7878
contest main org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 10.13.0.69:7878 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at contest.contest.main(contest.java:25)
```

Comment: I don't think has anything to do with VPN, its problem with your java code. You are not writing properly to the Target URL and not terminating your connection properly, use Apache HTTP API instead of Native HTTPConnectionUrl.

Comment: refer my example in another questions to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be/49606275#49606275

Comment: @RedBoy Please read note 1 and 2: it works perfectly well if i try to reach another URL, like google.com. And it also works if i place target webserver on same subnet, not behind VPN

Comment: I understand your conclusion that it works if not behind firewall, but when you receive error like "end of file from server", it means your request reaching the server but you are not terminating the connection properly, just try Apache HTTP API, its not more then a few minutes of code change.

Comment: @RedBoy i updated my code and issue description. Now i see error:  target server failed to respond