# class file of org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe not found,how can i fix it on intellij idea?

Tags: java, apache

```
message:javac 1.8.0_172 was used to compile java sources
error:java: 
Inaccessible org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
Can not found class file of org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe

C:...\common\HttpUtils.java 
warn:java:
org.apache.http.impl.client's org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient is obsolete
```

Thanks in advance. I am searching for a long time on the net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://linuxtut.com/replacement-of-annotation-threadsafe-notthreadsafe-removed-in-httpcore-4.4.5-4d580/) the `@NotThreadSafe` annotation should be replaced with `@Contract (threading = org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadingBehavior.UNSAFE)` which uses `org.apache.http.annotation.Contract`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/the-type-defaulthttpclient-is-deprecated/) for the error.

DefaultHttpClient is deprecated, you can this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be) here to import the Java HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 4.5.2 httpclient to 4.4.4 httpcore.

https://httpclient-users.hc.apache.narkive.com/79IE9RdD/trouble-compiling-httpcomponents-client-4-5-2-due-to-missing-org-apache-http-annotation-immutable