# Http Post request with Http Connection Pool

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot

I want to create a HTTP Connection pool  with a fixed URL at Application start-up and when ever i need  to send http post request  i will pick connection from pool and after using same connection need to be return in pool.

Suppose url is http://localhost:8082/test

environment:- spring boot

Please guide me how can i achieve the same.

Comment: If you are using Apache HttpClient you can achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851535/http-connection-pooling-using-httpclient

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV  please share some sample link for the same if possible

Comment: @NaveenKumarMishra you can refer this http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management